# Hot surface ignitor does not glow occasionally

Tags: furnace, gas

Can one of you experts please help with this unusual issue?
The hot surface ignitor does not go on occasionally. So far, I had this issue 3 time in the past week.

My furnace:
York gas furnace with model number P3ucd12n07601a, 100K BTU, 80 %

What is the issue:
-   Thermostat calls for heat.
-   Inducer motor runs
-   After about 30 seconds, ignitor hot surface glows
-   Gas valve makes a klick 
-   The burner does not ignite
-   The ignitor hot surface goes off
-   The inducer motor keeps going 
-   The ignitor hot surface does not glow any more, even not after 30 minutes
-   I can measure no electricity on the ignitor. However, the L1 going to the control board is hot (126V).
-   I can measure 26 V on the pressure switch. 
-   I turn off the furnace, shutdown the electricity, open the leads, and wait for 10-15 minutes.
-   Then, I turn on the furnace, and everything goes well. The issue is resolved for a hours or days but it comes back again.

What I have done so far:
-   I called a technician, he came in and checked the furnace but he could not find out what the issue is because the issue did not accrue when he was there. He said it could be the control board.
-   Then, we replaced the ignitor hot surface and the control board but it did not help. The issue is still there.

---

*Answer converted to an edit:*

The issue happened last night and I was confused when I tested the pressure switch. 
I attached an image of my pressure switch. 
3 wires go into the switch, brown (goes to limit switch), yellow (comes from transformer), and red (goes to a relay).

When the furnace is off – when the thermostat is not calling for heat – I can measure 0 V on brown, yellow, and red. The wires yellow and red are connected via the pressure switch, brown is not connected to red or yellow.

When, the thermostat calls for heat, I can measure 25 V on yellow, coming from the transformer and going to the switch.

When the inducer motor is running for about 10 seconds, the wires yellow and red become disconnected (the switch is open), the wires brown and red get connected.

That is what I don’t understand: When yellow and red are disconnected, I think I should measure 0 V on red because yellow bring the volte and the switch is now open. However, I could can 25 V on red. The 25 V is not coming from the yellow wire (because the switch is open), it is coming from the relay. I tested it by disconnecting the red from the pressure switch and measuring the volt.

I am wondering why the relay is sending 25 V to the pressure switch and whether it is supposed to work that way? Any idea? 
[image]

Comment: I take it the burner is not lighting off? Also, when this is happening, is 24V making it to the gas valve and staying there, or is the voltage at the gas valve falling off?  And do you get this when you jumper R to W, or only when the thermostat is trying to call for heat?

Comment: Yes, the burner does not light when the issue (a continued failed cycle)happens. I have not checked the voltage on the gas valve but I will check when the issue happens next time. I did not hear a klick form the gas vale beside the first one that I mentioned above, no klick after that. I did not jumper. The issue happens when the thermostat calls for heat.

Comment: @user79636 Please [register](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) your account and then [merge](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them so you have access to edit, comment, and accept answers on your own question. Posting multiple responses as answers can result in an automated lock that can prevent others from assisting you.